# MATCH AGAINST in joined table results in an error

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. In a query which joins them together I try to make a full-text search like this:

```
SELECT o44_1_0.attr_80748_ AS attr_80737_, MATCH o44_1_0.attr_80748_ AGAINST ('something' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  AS relev  
FROM object_80726_ f1  
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
 SELECT id_field, attr_80748_ FROM (
   SELECT m0.id_field,  attr_80748_  FROM object_80738_ o
   INNER JOIN master_slave m0 ON (m0.id_object = 80726) AND (m0.id_master = 80738) AND m0.id_slave_field = o.id                        
   ORDER BY  o.id_order 
 ) AS o  GROUP BY id_field 
)  AS o44_1_0 ON f1.id = o44_1_0.id_field
```

It may look terrible for you, but do not pay any attention to details of the query. Just have a look at how I do a full-text search:

```
...MATCH o44_1_0.attr_80748_ AGAINST ('something' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  AS relev...
```

This part of the query results in an error:

```
Error Code : 1214
The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes
```

If I comment this out, then everything is ok. However, the error does not seem to be correct, because if I do a full-text search in the joined table itself, then the query runs without any problem. So, this works:

```
SELECT attr_80748_, MATCH attr_80748_ AGAINST ('something' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  AS relev  
FROM object_80738_
```

So, the very same table and the very same field, but this time mysql does not throw any error.

Comment: What MySQL version do you use? And which storage engine are those tables using? Is one a MyISAM table and an other one InnoDB?

Comment: I use 5.5.23 version and MyISAM tables. So, they are both MyISAM

Comment: It's your materialized subselect that produces this error message.

Comment: I think you've got to rewrite your query so that your MATCH is used on the table directly and not on the result of a subselect.

Comment: Unfortunalely, that is impossible. The query is built by an algorithm in my application and it is heavily used here and there. So, it would be a nigthmare to rethink the whole architecture of the query builder just because of one single problem.

Comment: See the problem in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afabd8/4). Only one table, a MyISAM one. If you can't change your query builder then you can't use MATCH. You could select your result (without MATCH) into an (temporary) MyISAM table first and query this table.

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm unable to find a relevant restriction in the official list - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-restrictions.html. Is it undocumented?

Comment: I ran earlier today into [this post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,388258,388452#msg-388452) and so I do assume that typically such temporary tables are using the MEMORY storage engine, while the current documentation of the FULLTEXT functions are stating that only MyISAM and InnoDB (since MySQL 5.6) are supporting fulltext and only MyISAM is able to use IN BOOLEAN MODE without a fulltext index. So I had a try to reproduce this with a very simple query.

Comment: Thanks, VMai. I'm looking forward to hearing from you, as you progress in this area. Please, let me know.

Comment: Since your query would not use an fulltext index anyway, why don't you use INSTR() instead?

Comment: It uses it, I just cut off my queries for simplicity. But still I will consider using INSTR instead.